# 404 Nicht gefunden: Invalid Request jax ws web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws

I wrote a java jax-ws web service.
I used [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/) tutorial

After implementation I deployed my web service on my local tomcat. But I only get the following text on the website:

404 Nicht gefunden: Invalid Request

Have anybody a solution for such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error described above means "404 not found: Invalid Request" check if the URL of the WebService you are requesting is correct.

Comment: Oh no, you are right. Sorry. There was a slash "/" at the end. After I delete this, it works.